# salesforce mobile sdk access to UserInfo class

Tags: rest-api, community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, multi-currency, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have created a mobile app in Android and iOS using the Salesforce SDK. I want to add functionality of multi currency by using isMultiCurrencyOrganization() method from the UserInfo class. Now I am quite new to Salesforce mobile SDK so I don't know how I can use the methods of UserInfo class and check if user's organization has multi-currency enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of doing this is to use the SOAP API. You would concatenate strings to create the request - for example:

```
String req = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com\">"+
"  <soapenv:Header>"+
"     <urn:SessionHeader>"+
"        <urn:sessionId>"+client.getAuthToken()+"</urn:sessionId>"+
"     </urn:SessionHeader>"+
"  </soapenv:Header>"+
"  <soapenv:Body>"+
"     <urn:getUserInfo />"+
"  </soapenv:Body>"+
"</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

POSTing this request to `client.getInstanceUrlAsString()+"/services/Soap/c/31.0/"+client.getClientInfo().orgId` would result in a response like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/</a>"
  xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Body>
     <getUserInfoResponse>
        <result>
           <accessibilityMode>false</accessibilityMode>
           <currencySymbol>$</currencySymbol>
           <organizationId>00DD0000000EEW9MAO</organizationId>
           <organizationMultiCurrency>false</organizationMultiCurrency>
           <organizationName>Acme</organizationName>
           <profileId>00eD0000000v3qnIAA</profileId>
           <roleId xsi:nil="true"/>
           <userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode xsi:nil="true"/>
           <userEmail>jsmith@acme.com</userEmail>
           <userFullName>John Smith</userFullName>
           <userId>005D0000000nWYVIA2</userId>
           <userLanguage>en_US</userLanguage>
           <userLocale>en_US</userLocale>
           <userName>jsmith@acme.com</userName>
           <userTimeZone>America/Los_Angeles</userTimeZone>
           <userType>Standard</userType>
           <userUiSkin>Theme2</userUiSkin>
        </result>
     </getUserInfoResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You would need to parse the value for `organizationMultiCurrency` out of that XML.

Comment: I imported com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestClient.ClientInfo but the method client.getInstanceUrlAsString() is not available. Any suggestions on this would be really helpful

Comment: Do you maybe need to get a more recent version? I see it in the docs: http://forcedotcom.github.io/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/com/salesforce/androidsdk/rest/RestClient.ClientInfo.html#getInstanceUrlAsString()

Comment: Hi I managed to get client.getInstanceUrlAsString() working. But the Soap url returns GET not supported. HTTP ERROR 405. Could you please tell me how to find the SOAP API version.

Comment: Use POST, as I said in the answer.

Comment: Sorry for troubling again...I've solved the above issues, but using POST method, I get an HTTPFileNotFound exception. Any clues?

Comment: I can't easily investigate this as I don't have access to my work laptop right now. What actual URL are you POSTing to? It should look something like `https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/31.0/00DU0000000Q4f0` but with your instance instead of na1 and your org id at the end.

Comment: Yes this is the exact format of the url i passed with my instance and orgid. And I am building a native app.

 I found a solution to some extent.
I used the [select IsoCode  from CurrencyType where IsActive='true' ] and got a list of all the supported currencies. 
But, none of the fields e.g. DefaultCurrencyIsoCode, CurrencyIsoCode etc. Would work  for a single currency organization.
so the only issue left is that how can I fetch the default currency code of an organization which has multi currency disabled. 

Thanks